# Which formula to use to get value of a cell whose address is in another cell? (MS Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on some data which gives me the cell's address I have to fetch data from. Here's how it looks like -

[image]

`F` column combines the value of columns `D` & `E` to prepare address of target cell (in this case, it's `B4`). Now in `G` column, I want to get value of the cell (whose address is in `F` column), and check if it's value is `>25` using `IF()`. For example in this case, it should show yes, as the value in B4 is greater than 25...

Is there any formula which allows me to get text of a cell whose address is in another cell? Kindly guide... Thanks!

***Note:** The values of D & E are dynamic, therefore I can't just link-in B4 (It can be A2/B1/etc. sometimes)*

Comment: Simple answer is using `INDIRECT()`. More complicated answer would be using (non-volatile) `INDEX`: `=INDEX(1:1048576,E2,CODE(UPPER(D2))-64)`

Comment: Or keep it a simple `IF()` in case only column B or A can be referenced.

Comment: Thanks @P.b! `=INDIRECT(F2)` works perfectly for me. 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @P.b in comments for the solution.

---

`=INDIRECT()` works the best for me... Thanks! :)